# Getting this issue "Failed to initialize a pipeline" when I do a SSL connection to cassandra

Tags: ssl, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

**Connecting to Cassandra with non-SSL port works. 
But when I try to make a SSL connection by initializing SSLContext, I get this strange exception.
I am using Datastax driver cassandra-driver-core-2.0.0-rc3.jar**

Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: Failed to initialize a pipeline.
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:208) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.(Connection.java:92) [cassandra-driver-core-2.0.0-rc3.jar:]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:421) [cassandra-driver-core-2.0.0-rc3.jar:]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:215) [cassandra-driver-core-2.0.0-rc3.jar:]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:170) [cassandra-driver-core-2.0.0-rc3.jar:]

Comment: 1. Can you share the code you are using the setup the `Cluster` instance?; 2. Do you have SSL enabled on all your nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Java Unlimited Strength JCE; this has to be done on your client machine in your JRE installation.

Here is one reference in the context of the Cassandra server, but Java clients using SSL need this as well.

http://www.pathin.org/tutorials/java-cassandra-cannot-support-tls_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha-with-currently-installed-providers/